# Swap two values in a numpy array.

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, swap

Is there something more efficient than the following code to swap two values of a numpy 1D array?

```
input_seq = arange(64)

ix1 = randint(len(input_seq))
ixs2 = randint(len(input_seq))

temp = input_seq[ix2]
input_seq[ix2] = input_seq[ix1] 
input_seq[ix1] = temp
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a standardized method to swap two variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python)

Comment: Can you please post a short example of both inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: definitely **not** a duplicate of that other question, because this one here is asking specifically about numpy...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use tuple unpacking. Tuple unpacking allows you to avoid the use of a temporary variable in your code (in actual fact I believe the Python code itself uses a temp variable behind the scenes but it's at a much lower level and so is much faster).

```
input_seq[ix1], input_seq[ix2] = input_seq[ix2], input_seq[ix1]
```

I have flagged this question as a duplicate, the answer in [the dupe post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python) has a lot more detail.

Comment: This does not seem safe on NumPy arrays. Try:

    A = np.ones((2,2));
    A[1,:] += 1;
    A[0,:], A[1,:] = A[1,:], A[0,:];

`A` now has 2s all over.

Comment: The answer by @lewistrick will work on numpy arrays of arbitrary dimension.  This answer will fail on dimension 2 or higher.

Comment: This may work for single values (answering the question in the strictest sense), but not groups of values. Try `a=np.array([1,2,3]); b=np.array([4,5,6,7]); a[0:3], b[0:3] = b[0:3], a[0:3]`. The result will be that the first 3 values in b get moved to a, but the a values don't copy  into b. This is likely due to passing pointers (i.e. a gets overwritten by b values and THEN copied into b). It's what makes this question interesting IMHO.  Adding `.copy()` helps, e.g. `a, b[0:3] = (b[0:3]).copy(), a` works.

Answer (score 54):

I see you're using numpy arrays. In that case, you can also do this:

```
input_seq[[ix1, ix2]] = input_seq[[ix2, ix1]]
```