# Python while loop. What is this construct called?

Tags: python, data-structures, while-loop

On the Literate Programs site, I was looking at the Python code for the GCD algorithm.

```
def gcd(a,b):
        """ the euclidean algorithm """
        while a:
                a, b = b%a, a
        return b
```

What is going on in the body? Expression evaluation? Is it a compressed form of another structure?

Comment: [link](http://en.literateprograms.org/Euclidean_algorithm_(Python))

Comment: There's no structure. it's just parallel assignment `x, y = 3, 4` is the same as doing `x = 3` and `y = 4` separately.

Comment: Do you mean the multiple assignment or the numeric evaluation as logical value?

Comment: Thank you - I thought it was something like the 'swap variables without a temp var' idea. Which uses tuples: a, b, c = b, c, a

Comment: Maybe it is Friday afternoon - but I just don't get it. "While a exists give me an 'a' and a 'b' which is modulus b over a ..."

Comment: OH - Thank you - it *is* like a, b = b, a . I was reading it as 3 expressions not 4. it is clear now. I get it

Comment: (umm - how do I show appreciation and close this?)

Comment: @mbubb - You would accept the most helpful answer by clicking the check next to it.  Doing so lets people know that this problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

```
            a, b = b%a, a
```

First, a tuple is created with the contents `(b%a, a)`. Then the contents of that tuple are [unpacked](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) and assigned to the names `a` and `b`.

Comment: Thank you - I was reading it as 3 expressions seperated by commas - I was not seeing: x,y = y,x

Answer (score 1):

Looks like shorthand for:

```
while a > 0:
    temp = a
    a = b%a
    b = temp
return b
```

Comment: Where does the temp come in? ;)

Comment: It stores the old value of `a` so that when `a` is overwritten, we still have its original value for storing into `b`. The Python shorthand in the question doesn't need it but if we split it up like this we need to introduce this separate variable.

Comment: No, I mean look at your code... `temp = a`, you mutate `a` and then take the mutated `a` and assign it `b`.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is receiving the result of `b%a` while `b` is receiving the value of `a`

Works the same as:

```
while a > 0:
    tmp = a
    a = b%a
    b = tmp
return b
```

See this post for more information on switching variables: [Is there a standardized method to swap two variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python)