# What do the commas mean in a statement like: a,b=b,a?

Tags: python

I would like to know what the commas mean in line 5

```
def insertion_sort(items):
    for i in range(1, len(items)):
        j = i
        while j > 0 and items[j] < items[j-1]:
            items[j], items[j-1] = items[j-1], items[j]
            j -= 1
```

Comment: it means they are [tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a standardized method to swap two variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python)

Comment: @MattDMo, not it means they are _sequences_. Not just tuples.

Answer (score 1):

it means swap `items[j]` and `items[j-1]`

Comment: How can i do this in a more basic way, i didn't take this method in my class yet!

Comment: @OmarSherief It's not exactly advanced. It's shorthand for `items[j] = items[j-1]` and `items[j-1] = items[j]`, except it lets you avoid using a temporary valuable.

Comment: @royhowie I'm sorry i just started programming and i wanna know how to do it without commas. Thank you. So what should i do?

Comment: @OmarSherief Look at Vishnu or Mahesh's answer. They cover that.

Comment: The way that "works without commas" is less "basic" by any reasonable measure.

Answer (score 1):

The comma on the right generates the tuple `(b, a)`. The one on the left uses **sequence unpacking** to take the elements of the sequence on the right of the equals sign and bind them one by one to the names on the left. Hence the overall operation is to swap the objects bound to `a` and `b`.

[more info](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

Answer (score 0):

its like this,

```
>>> a, b = 2, 10
>>> temp = a
>>> a = b
>>> b = temp
>>> a
10
>>> b
2
```

In you case,

```
items[j], items[j-1] = items[j-1], items[j]
```

it will process like:-

```
 temp = items[j]
 item[j] = items[j-1j
 items[j-1] = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

It is use to assign a value `items[j]=items[j-1]` and   `items[j-1] = items[j]` 
in a single line you can write like `items[j], items[j-1] = items[j-1], items[j]`
exchange the value of item here the like `swap`.

example :

```
          >>> a,b=10,20
          >>> a
          10
          >>> b
          20
         >>> a,b
         (10, 20)
```