# Odd behavior in Fibonacci series in python 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This does not print the correct Fibonacci series i.e. 1 1 2 3 5 8...

```
print ('Fibonacci series...')
 a,b = 0,1
 while b<50:
  print(b)
  a = b
  b = a + b
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, there is an indentation error in the first code snippet. The last two lines should be indented so they are executed within the `while` loop.

```
print ('Fibonacci series...')
a,b = 0,1
while b<50:
 print(b)
 a = b
 b = a+b
```

However, this still won't produce the correct result. Let's look at why these two code snippets are different.

1. `a, b = b, a + b`: This will assign `a` to `b` and `b` to `a + b`, with the evaluation of the right-hand side before the left-hand side. This means before looking at what variables to assign new values to, Python will first see what `b` and `a + b` are. This means the old value of `a` will be used for setting `b = a + b`. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python/14836456#14836456).

   ```
   a = 1
   b = 2
   a, b = b, a + b  # set a to 2, set b to 1 + 2
   print(a)  # 2
   print(b)  # 3
   ```
2. `a = b; b = a + b`: This does assignment sequentially, such that `a` is first set to `b`, then used in the assignment calculation.

   ```
   a = 1
   b = 2
   a = b  # set a to 2
   b = a + b  # set b to 2 + 2
   print(a)  # 2
   print(b)  # 4
   ```

Answer (score 2):

```
a=b
b = a+b
```

in the first code sample is equivalent to `b = b * 2`. Instead you want `b += original_value(a)`. So you either need to do tuple assignment, as in the second code sample (`a,b = b, a+b`), or use a temp variable:

```
temp = a
a = b
b += temp
```

to get the desired value changes.