# Trouble understanding python syntax for assigning variables

Tags: python, debugging, syntax, fibonacci

I'm looking at this fibonacci sequence program from python

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# simple fibonacci series
# the sum of two elements defines the next set
a, b = 0, 1
while b < 50:
    print(b)
    a, b = b, a + b
print("Done")
```

The resulting output looks like this: `1, 1, 2 ,3 ,5 ,8 ,13 ,21, 34, Done`

I'm slightly confused by the syntax of `a, b = b, a + b`

What's an equivalent version of this that is more expanded out?

**EDIT ANSWER**

Okay after reading up on things, below is one equivalent way, with a `c` temporary placeholder to grab original `a`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# simple fibonacci series
# the sum of two elements defines the next set
a = 0
b = 1
c = 0
while b < 50:
    print(b)
    c = a
    a = b
    b = a + c
print("Done")
```

More ways here: [Is there a standardized method to swap two variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python) , including tuples, xor, and temp variable (like here)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python

Comment: it's a double assignment. `a` takes the value of `b`, while `b` takes the value of the original `a+b`

Comment: I found this site to be invaluable in understanding some of what Python does:  http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a,%20b%20%3D%200,%201%0Awhile%20b%20%3C%2050%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%28b%29%0A%20%20%20%20a,%20b%20%3D%20b,%20a%20%2B%20b%0Aprint%28%22Done%22%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=30&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Comment: thumbtack this looks very helpful! has every debug line of code :). Any other tools you recommend ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a, b = b, a + b`

is the equivalent of

`a = b; b = a + b` except this would use the new value of `a` when assigning to `b`, not the original as intended.

Comment: so that's not the equivalent...

Comment: Right, hence the exception I specified.

Comment: does this mean to the equivalent of `a , b = b, a+b` you would have to use a temporary variable `c` to store the original value `a` to get a large expanded version?

Comment: That would be a way to solve this issue, yes, but not the most Pythonic.