# Why does computational time decrease when removing unnecessary items from a list in Python

Tags: python, time-complexity, fibonacci

The past days I've been trying get a better understanding of computational complexity and how to improve Python code. For this I have tried out different functions for calculating Fibonacci numbers, comparing how long the script runs if I make small changes.

I'm calculating Fibonacci numbers using a list, adding the sum of element -2 and -1 from the list.

I was puzzled to find that if I add a .pop() in the loop, deleting not needed elements of my list, my script runs significantly faster. I don't see why this is. Each step in the loop the computer does one more thing. So my untrained intuition suggests that this should increase computational time. Is 'looking up' the last element of the list so much slower when the list is very long?

Here is my code:

```
import time
import numpy as np

def fib_stack1(n):
    """ Original function """
    assert type(n) is int, 'Expected an integer as input.'
    if n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        stack = [0, 1]
        for i in range(n-1):
            stack.append(stack[-1] + stack[-2])
        return stack[-1]

def fib_stack2(n):
    """ Modified function """
    assert type(n) is int, 'Expected an integer as input.'
    if n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        stack = [0, 1]
        for i in range(n-1):
            stack.append(stack[-1] + stack[-2])
            ### CHANGE ###
            stack.pop(-3)
            ##############
        return stack[-1] 


rec1 = []
rec2 = []
for _ in range(10):
    t1 = time.time()
    fib_stack1(99999)  
    t2 = time.time()
    rec1.append(t2-t1)
    t1 = time.time()
    fib_stack2(99999)  
    t2 = time.time()
    rec2.append(t2-t1)
print(np.array(rec1).mean())
print(np.array(rec2).mean())
```

The output is the following:

```
# Original 
0.26878631115
# Modified
0.145034956932
```

Comment: The short answer is yes. Additionally, you can completely cut out the list and see further improvements

Comment: What Python version are you on?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention it: I'm using Python 3.5 
And if that is also of interest: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is 'looking up' the last element of the list so much slower when the list is very long?

No, list length has no effect on lookup speed. These are arraylists, not linked lists. It's more likely that this is related to memory allocation or cache performance. The garbage collector is also involved.

When you delete unneeded list elements, Python never has to allocate a bigger buffer for the list. It may also be able to reuse the memory allocated for the `int` objects instead of requesting more memory from the OS. Considering how huge your integers get, reusing their memory is a big deal. (The details of memory allocation depend on the Python version and the underlying standard library allocator. Python 2 has a free list for `int`s, but not `long`s; Python 3 has no free list for `int`s. Python itself makes no effort to reuse allocations for large objects, but the underlying allocator might be doing something.)

Additionally, when you have to keep allocating new integers, especially ones as huge as the 99999th Fibonacci number, you're not going to get much benefit out of your CPU's cache. Main memory access is much slower than cache.

Finally, the allocation pattern of your `fib_stack1` (lots of allocations, not so many object refcounts falling to 0) triggers Python's cycle-detector system, a.k.a. the garbage collector, which takes time to run and touches a lot of memory that didn't need touching, hurting cache performance. Temporarily [disabling the collector](http://ideone.com/mFuBkB) produces a notable speedup for `fib_stack1` in my own tests, especially on Python 3.

Comment: Using as an opportunity for a redirect. The answer by @jean prompted me to start researching contiguous memory for python lists, which was surprising for me considering how much emphasis `numpy` puts on this for speed (implying that it's part of the reason it's faster than Python), and I've seen you pop up a few times in my search. I assume the contiguous issue then applies in cases on multi-dimensional lists/arrays where they start to differ? Do you know of any good answers to direct my search to understand this?

Comment: @roganjosh: I'm not actually sure what you're asking. Lists are noncontiguous in the sense that they store pointers to their elements, but the pointers are stored contiguously. NumPy arrays aren't always contiguous, particularly arrays that are views of other data, but unlike lists, they don't store an array of pointers (unless they're `object` arrays).

Comment: @roganjosh: You might be interested in the [NumPy internals documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.html) and the [list object implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c). If you have plenty of free time, you might be interested in reading some of the [NumPy core implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy/core/src).

Comment: And that immediately highlights the limitation of my thought process, thanks. I was thinking along the lines of, say, a 2D list of ints of mismatched dimensions, in which case I wasn't seeing why memory allocation should be different between numpy (which then wouldn't  be contiguous) and the python list

Comment: It went back to a previous discussion in comments in which I wasn't sure why a 3D array containing a square 2D array couldn't be contiguous for the 2D array (I was trying to store a matrix and metadata about that matrix in a single array). You suggested that I store metadata and the square matrix separately. I don't know C so it's tough for me to truly get a view of what's happening, but your first comment shows my oversight. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

A `list` stores its elements in memory in a *contiguous* way.

So the `append` method of the `list` object needs to resize the allocated memory block from time to time (not every time `append` is called, fortunately)

Sometimes, the system is able to resize "in-place" (allocates further memory just after the current memory block), and sometimes not: it has to find a contiguous block of memory big enough to store the new list.

When the resize is not "in-place", existing data needs to be copied. (Note that doesn't happen when the size of the list *decreases*)

So if there are less elements in the list when it's copied, operations are faster.

Note that `list.append` remains extremely fast. Adding at the end of a list is the fastest way (compared to `insert` which has to move elements each time to free its "slot")

Comment: Considering how huge the ints get, I suspect allocations for the list aren't actually that important.

Comment: @user2357112 you may be right about that. The answer was more a generic one about which is faster: appending to a short list or to a long list. Your cache idea is also a good lead.

Comment: @TonyTannous much appreciated :) although I agree that it may not be the only or main speed factor in that particular case.

Comment: I had a similar problem, appending becomes slower as the list grows. I think using `garbage collector` helped.

Comment: well, possible, if garbage collector frees some memory so list resize can be contiguous more frequently (less memory copy).

Answer (score 3):

No, looking up any element in a list is done in the same amount of time (what is known as constant time behavior in computer science). Adding the call to `pop` does increase the work needed in each loop iteration a little, but the list never gets bigger than 3 elements. In your first version, the list grows in each iteration, and such an operation can either be *completely free* or *quite expensive*, depending on how much *additional* memory the list has actually allocated under the hood, an information which is not directly accessible.

Basically, when you instantiate a list, some additional space is preallocated, making room for future `append`s on the expense of "wasting" space. If the list gets filled up, it needs to be enlarged for further `append`s to happen, and so these particular appends are much more expensive than usually. If some other data is already present in memory at the end of the array, *all* of the data (actually just pointers) in the list elements has to be copied over to a new memory location where the entire, new list can be stored in one, contiguous chunk of memory.

For more information about list growth behavior (in CPython only, as this is implementation specific), see e.g. [here](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/)

Answer (score -1):

The overhead of maintaining the list outweighs the additional operation. This can be proven by [inspecting the size of the resulting list as the functions run](https://repl.it/repls/CompassionateDaringBusinesssoftware):

```
# Func      List Size (Sum of Elements Size)
fib_stack1: 120 (72)
fib_stack1: 90136 (4888568)
fib_stack1: 162720 (19034164)
fib_stack1: 260864 (42436332)
fib_stack1: 330256 (75095060)
fib_stack1: 418080 (117010332)
fib_stack1: 529224 (168182184)
fib_stack1: 595424 (228610568)
fib_stack1: 669896 (298295536)
fib_stack1: 753680 (377237048)

fib_stack2: 112 (48)
fib_stack2: 112 (1904)
fib_stack2: 112 (3752)
fib_stack2: 112 (5608)
fib_stack2: 112 (7456)
fib_stack2: 112 (9312)
fib_stack2: 112 (11160)
fib_stack2: 112 (13008)
fib_stack2: 112 (14864)
fib_stack2: 112 (16712)

fib_stack3: 48
fib_stack3: 1904
fib_stack3: 3752
fib_stack3: 5608
fib_stack3: 7456
fib_stack3: 9312
fib_stack3: 11160
fib_stack3: 13008
fib_stack3: 14864
fib_stack3: 16712
```

**NOTE:**

- In the first case, python **doesn't know you don't need the old values** so it has to index and store all previous values, to include, as others have mentioned, copying over that list as it needs to allocate more memory.
- In the second case, **python doesn't have to store the old values, so the list is not growing since add/pop every time**. It removes item zero, copies all larger items back one space, then continues.
- In the third case (described below), we remove the list intermediate and just manually apply the transform. This is why the sum of element size for `fib_stack2` is equivalent to the two integers combined in `fib_stack3`.

Further improvements can be had by not making the list to begin with:

```
def fib_stack3(n):
    """ Modified function """
    assert type(n) is int, 'Expected an integer as input.'
    if n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        second_anc, first_anc = 0, 1
        for i in range(n-1):
            second_anc, first_anc = first_anc, second_anc + first_anc
        return first_anc
```

Running all three on repl.it gives:

```
fib_stack1 1.3875333309173583
fib_stack2 0.41049718856811523
fib_stack3 0.33348443508148196
```

Clearly the last case, where we don't bother with a list at all, wins out.

This is because we're no longer inching our list down, we're just reusing the same two integers. This works because python [evaluates the right side before the left](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14836456/3579910) and therefore allows single line swaps.