# Python assignment operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have these two programs what is the difference in assignment of these two values which print different outputs.

```
>>> a=0
>>> b=1
>>> while b<10:
...     print(b)
...     a=b
...     b=a+b
```

output:
1
2
4
8
and

```
>>>a=0
>>> b=1
>>> while b<10:
...     print(b)
...     a, b = b, a+b
```

output:1
1
2
3
5
8

Thx,
Arun

Comment: Not a duplicate but closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14836228/5647260 -- explains execution step by step.

Answer (score 2):

The order in which `a+b` is calculated changes.

In the first case, `a+b` is calculated after `a=b` is executed.

In the second case, `a+b` is calculated before any assignment happens.

In general, what happens in Python is that things at the right of `=` are evaluated before the assignment happens.

---

If you're curious, you can take a look of what's happening behind the scenes using `dis`, that will show you the bytecode:

```
>>> dis.dis('a, b = b, a+b')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)     # Push the value of 'b' on top of the stack
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (a)     # Push the value of 'a'
              4 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)     # Push the value of 'b'
              6 BINARY_ADD                         # Compute the sum of the last two values on the stack
             # Now the stack contains the value of 'b' and of 'a+b', in this order
              8 ROT_TWO                            # Swap the two values on top of the stack
             # Now the stack contains the value of 'a+b' and of 'b', in this order
             10 STORE_NAME               1 (a)     # Store the value on top of the stack inside 'a'
             12 STORE_NAME               0 (b)     # Store the value on top of the stack inside 'b'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - @Andrea Corbellini