# Don't understand cycle sort in python

Tags: arrays, list, loops, sorting, for-loop

I have been viewing the article Cycle sort on Wikipedia which has an implementation in python which I don't understand.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_sort

What do the lines like this do?

```
array[pos], item = item, array[pos]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a standardized method to swap two variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python)

Comment: Without knowing much about Python, I'd guess this is a swap of `item` and `array[pos]`

Comment: As an additional clarification, it's a swap, but since `item` is a local variable, from the view point of cycle sort, where the goal is to minimize the number of writes, the only "write" is to `array[pos]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interactive Python session which answers your question (in short: the `array[pos]` gets swapped with the `item`):

```
In [1]: array = [1,2,3]

In [2]: pos = 0

In [3]: item = 4

In [4]: array[pos], item = item, array[pos]

In [5]: array
Out[5]: [4, 2, 3]

In [6]: item
Out[6]: 1
```