# confused about LPTHW ex41: about the PHRASE_FIRST code

Tags: python, dictionary

```
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english":
    PHRASE_FIRST == True
```

Actually I do know the function of these codes, but when I type 
into only 1 argument when I try to run it, the result is no 
different from the one when I follow the code typing into 2 
arguments and the second one is "english".From my understanding, it supposes to be different in subsequent code.

```
for snippet in snippets: 
    phrase = PHRASES[snippet] 
    question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase) 

    if PHRASE_FIRST:
        question, answer = answer, question
```

And also, I don't know what's this line for... to exchange values? But I didn't see any changes when the PHRASE_FIRST is True or False.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up `=` and `==`.

In your second line, use `PHRASE_FIRST = True` (only one `=`). What you have right now is a test whether `PHRASE_FIRST` is `True` (`==`). But you want to **change the value** of `PHRASE_FIRST`. Therefore only use one `=`.

As for your second question (swap values) you're correct. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python)

Comment: oh! I see! thanks! It works after I change == into =

Comment: @MillieHU Great! If this is the correct answer, consider to upvote and/or mark as accepted.