# I'm confused as to why we can't swap variables using a specific method

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, methods, swap

I have two variables, x and y, and I want to swap their values. (For example, if x has value 20 and y has value "princess", then after the swap I want x to have value "princess" and y to have value 20.)

Can you explain why the code
x = y
y = x
doesn't work.

I know how to use the temp variable and x,y but I was confused as to why the above method doesn't work.
I have no code except for

```
x=y
y=x
```

I just need someone to explain why the method above doesn't work.

Comment: Think about what would happen in this code. Once you've done `x=y`, what has happened to the original value of `x`?

Comment: This is a great question to trace manually on paper. Make a column for `x` and a column for `y`. Put the initial values in each column. Trace through each line of code and update the variable values in each column. See what happens.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, once you assign the value of `y` to `x`, you no longer have a reference to `x`'s original value so the next operation doesn't work.

Try:

```
y,x = x,y
```

---

[Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 2):

I'll explain with an example:

```
x = 20 
y = 5 

x = y ---> x is now 5 
y = x ---> y is now 5 too
```

If you want to swap them, you need to do in python e.g.:

```
x, y = y, x
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python)

Edit: 
You mentioned that you want to assign the values "princess" - a String and 20 - an integer. 
In (most) programming languages you define the data type of the variable and you can't assign an integer to variable which was defined as a String and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `x = 5` and `y=10`.

After `x = y` is executed, `x = 10` and `y = 10`.

After `y = x` is executed, `x` still `= 10` and `y` still `= 10`.

So `x = y = 10`.

To swap two variables, Python has this built in: use `x, y = y, x`.