# why swaping of two numbers in python in the following way gives syntax error in python programming

Tags: python, swap

i want to swap two numbers in the following way but i don't know why it gives the syntax error

```
numOne = 10;

numTwo = 20;

numTwo = numOne + numTwo - (numOne = numTwo);
```

it gives syntax error at = of (numOne = numTwo)

is there any reason and the solution??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a standardized method to swap two variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

An assignment statement, e.g. `x = y`, is not an *expression* in Python.  So while chained assignments are allowed, e.g. `a = b = c`, embedded assignments using the `=` operator or not.

That having been said, Python 3.8 introduced the "walrus operator", `:=`, which allows assignment expressions.  So in Python 3.8 and later, you can do:

```
numTwo = numOne + numTwo - (numOne := numTwo)
```

to achieve the desired result.  You can read about the walrus operator [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) and, in more detail, [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).

But in Python, the normal way to swap two variables `a` and `b` is:

```
a, b = b, a
```

That's all that's needed.

Also note that none of the semicolons in the posted code are necessary, and would normally not be present.

Answer (score 0):

Just split the assignment and calculation into separate statements.
Python is neither C not C++, assignment operator does not return anything, so most likely you’re trying to perform some mathematical operation on `None`. Imagine adding `int` and `void` in C, that wouldn’t work either, right?

Answer (score 0):

swapping 2 number is super easy in python:

```
numOne = 10;

numTwo = 20;

numOne, numTwo = numTwo, numOne
```