# problem with sorting array with native method

Tags: python, sorting

my method for sorting an array written in python:

```
array = [3, 2, 1]

for i in range(len(array)):
    minVal = array[i]
    for j in range(i + 1, len(array)):
        if (array[j] < array[i]):
            if (array[j] <= minVal):
                minVal = array[j]
    if i < len(array) - 1:
        array[i + 1] = array[i]
        array[i] = minVal

print(array)
```

how do i think it works?
the first cycle will be executed 3 times
first iteration:

```
#i will check number 3 with numbers 2 and 1
#expected output:
minVal = 1
array = [1, 3, 2]
```

second iteration:

```
#i will check number 3 with number 2
#expected output:
minVal = 2
array = [1, 2, 3]
```

last iteration:

```
#I do not know if he is needed.
#perhaps it is worth writing `range(len(array) - 1)` in the first loop?
#and because of this iteration, I also added the check `if i <len (array) - 1:`
```

expected output at the end: `[1, 2, 3]`
what i got: `[1, 1, 3]`

Comment: `if (array[j] < array[i]):` isn't needed and the condition at the end doesn't make sense. Are you trying to write [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)?

Comment: I try to write as I think in my head, I do not take an example from different algorithms

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: You should also read about [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) which you were on the verge of doing without knowing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about your logic: You find the minimum value and then replace the `i` item with it but only advance the `i` item one index ahead to `i+1`. By doing so, after the first iteration you have the list as `[1, 3, 1]`. Let's break it down:

- you start with `[3, 2, 1]`
- `minVal = array[i] = 3`
- After the `j` loop we find that `minVal = 1`
- Now we do `array[i + 1] = array[i] -> array[1] = 3`. So now we have `[3, 3, 1]`.
- Now we do `array[i] = minVal -> array[0] = 1`. So now we have `[1, 3, 1]`.

The element `2` has disappeared from the list!

To fix this, you need to save the `minVal`'s index and replace the two items, not override another item:

```py
array = [3, 2, 1]

for i in range(len(array)):
    minIndex = i
    for j in range(i + 1, len(array)):
        if (array[j] < array[i]):
            if (array[j] <= array[minIndex]):
                minIndex = j
    minVal = array[minIndex]
    if i < len(array) - 1:
        array[minIndex] = array[i]
        array[i] = minVal

print(array)
```

---

Now there are some points to simplify and improve your code:

- There is no need to check that `array[j] < array[i]` on every iteration - in the first iteration it is equal to `minVal`/`array[minIndex]` anyway, so you can remove one `if`.
- There is no need for the last `if` - instead of checking every iteration if we got to the last element, just remove it from the loop - `for i in range(len(array)-1)`.
- The replacement can be done in one line without the need to even save `minVal` - see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python).

So the improved version according to the above can be:

```py
array = [3, 2, 1]

for i in range(len(array)-1):
    minIndex = i
    for j in range(i + 1, len(array)):
        if array[j] < array[minIndex]:
            minIndex = j

    array[minIndex], array[i] = array[i], array[minIndex]

print(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently searching an array for the minimum value including and past the current index. This is an `O(N^2)` approach, and quite robust. However, you need to implement it correctly.

The check

```
if (array[j] < array[i]):
        if (array[j] <= minVal):
```

is redundant. You shouldn't restrict your test by the original minimum value, although it does no harm, since `minVal <= array[i]` in all cases.

You don't really care about the *value* of `minVal` as much as you do about its location. You more-or-less correctly identify `minVal` as `array[j]`, but then you swap it out as `array[i + 1] = array[i]`. Where is the correct `j` recorded?

Here is the same idea, but without the extra check, and using `minJ` to illustrate the caching of `j` vs the value:

```
array = [3, 2, 1]

for i in range(len(array) - 1):       # Don't bother iterating the last element
    min_j = i                         # Only record indices
    for j in range(i + 1, len(array)):
        if array[j] < array[min_j]:   # Only test current minimum
            min_j = j
    array[i], array[min_j] = array[min_j], array[i]

print(array)
```

Couple of small tweaks:

- You don't need to iterate over the last element, so shorten the outer `range` by one.
- The idiomatic way to swap two quantities in python is `x, y = y, x`. If you're going to use a temporary variable anyway, it may as well be a tuple that enhances legibility.