# Rename Variable in Python Based on Condition

Tags: python, if-statement, variables, conditional-statements

Let `a=5` and `b=6`, I want to switch values when `a < b`. I can attempt this by making temporary variable say using code below

```
if a < b:
   a_temp = b
   b_temp = a
a = a_temp
b = b_temp
```

Is there an elegant way to do this without creating temporary variables?

Comment: You can swap both in a single assignment with `if a < b: a, b = b, a`, or using `min`, `max` or unpack `sorted`: `b, a = sorted((a, b))`

Comment: [Also check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a,b = max(a,b),min(a,b)
```

Assigns to a the maximum value and to b the minimum value, which seems to be what you are looking for