# difference between these two fibonacci python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, fibonacci

What is the difference between these two python code?.i thought both are same but the output i am getting is different

```
    def fibonacci(num):
        a=1
        b=1
        series=[]
        series.append(a)
        series.append(b)
        for i in range(1,num-1):
            series.append(a+b)
            #a,b=b,a+b
            a=b
            b=a+b
            
            
            
        return series
    print(fibonacci(10))
```

```
    def fibonacci(num):
        a=1
        b=1
        series=[]
        series.append(a)
        series.append(b)
        for i in range(1,num-1):
            series.append(a+b)
            a,b=b,a+b
            #a=b
            #b=a+b
            
            
            
        return series
    print(fibonacci(10))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a standardized method to swap two variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python)

Comment: thanks for the answer.But i want to know about the memory assignment part and why it is giving me different output

Comment: hey  thanks for the all the answers i got the full explanation below given by @M K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first method

```
a=b
b=a+b
```

is an incorrect way of swapping, when you say `a=b` you have lost the value of a, so `b=a+b` is the same as `b=b+b`, which is not what you want.

Another way to achieve an equivalent result to this approach, `a,b = b,a+b`,  is by using a temporary variable to store `a`, as follows:

```
tmp = a
a = b
b = tmp + b
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is about storing the values you are calculating, on the first snippet you are saying a+b only on the second snippet you are saying b =a+b. The value of b is changing when you say b = a+b.

Hope my explanation is understandable.You are re-assigning the value of b o the first snippet (b=a+b)