# Python Question How Python works in memory, if code is "a,b = b, a"

Tags: python

Python Question How Python works in memory, if code is  "a,b = b, a"

```
a = 1
b = 2

a, b = b, a
print(a, b)
# 2, 1
```

i search on internet but i don't find the solution

Comment: Any time you see a comma, that's a tuple in python. Don't let the lack of parentheses distract you. In this case it's optimized out using the stack directly, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Perhaps you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14836456/9475509).